# EF Codefirst AddOrUpdate with related entities as identifier

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I want to use AddorUpdate with setting an identifier expression using related entities.

My class:

```
Class Task
   property id as Integer
   property name as String
End Class
```

My relation class:

```
Class RelationTask
   property id as Integer
   property task as Task
   property parentTask as Task
End Class
```

now I want to add a relation like:

```
taskA = new Task with {.name = "A"}
taskB = new Task with {.name = "B"}
.... ' add tasks to context
context.RelationTasks.AddOrUpdate(function(r) r.task, new RelationTask with {.task = TaskB, .parentTask = TaskA})
```

This does not work (error "*Unable to create a constant value of type 'DataModel.Task'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*"), because I use an entity instead of a value...
How should I do this?

Also, a second question: how would I write the same but with multiple identifiers? I think something like `function(r) {r.task, r.parentTask}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answers, I tried to find a solution myself, but I can't believe that's the best way of doing it. Anyhow, I added the IDs of both related entities so I could use these as identifier:

```
Class Task
   property id as Integer
   property name as String
End Class

Class RelationTask
   property id as Integer
   property task as Task
   property taskId as Integer
   property parentTask as Task
   property parentTaskId as Integer
End Class


taskA = new Task with {.name = "A"}
taskB = new Task with {.name = "B"}
.... ' add tasks to context
context.RelationTasks.AddOrUpdate(function(r) New With {r.taskId, r.parentTaskId}, new RelationTask with {.task = TaskB, .parentTask = TaskA})
```

It is behaving as I want, but it doesn't feel good...